# NextsJS & Auth0 Protect Page Route

Tags: reactjs, next.js, auth0

Using following library / docs.
https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0.

There is an example at bottom of readme on a HOC that can be used to protect API routes `requireAuthentication`. Is there anything similar for pages? If not how would one best protect access to a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question was answered over on the example repo at GitHub here:
https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/issues/148